# Uncertain about linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question. If I want the vectors $y_1(t)=\bar{v_1}e^{\lambda t}$ and $y_2(t)=\bar{v_1}te^{\lambda t}+\bar{v_2}e^{\lambda t}$ to be linearly independent, why is it enough to show that $y_1(0)=\bar{v_1}$ and $y_2(0)=\bar{v_2}$ are?

Why does linear independence in one point imply linear independence in every point? Is it because linear independence in one point, implies that these two vector valued functions can not be linearly dependent?

Comment: If the functions were linearly dependent, there would be a linear combination equal to the 0 function. So that would continue to be true evaluating at 0.

Comment: @JohnBrevik Yes but what I dont get is why linear independence at $t=0$ would be enough to imply linear independence for all possible values of $t$?

Comment: Linear independence of functions doesn't mean linear independence at every single point. See my first comment. Linear _dependence_ of functions means that you actually get the $0$ _function_ out of a linear combination. (Actually, in your case $y_1(0) = 0$, so they are not linearly independent there. But $y_1(1)$ and $y_2(1)$ are linearly independent. So if $a_1y_1 + a_2y_2=0$ as functions for some scalars $a_1, a_2$, then $a_1y_1(t) + a_2y_2(t)=0$ for _every_ $t$-value. Take the contrapositive: If they're linearly independent for just one $t$-value, they are linearly independent as functions.

Comment: related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity for $x_0=0$ (applied to the system of linear differential equations).

Comment: So for two functions to be linearly independent it only sufficies to be linearly independent at a single $t$-value? Is there a proof regarding this somewhere or?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to proof that the two functions are linearly independent you have to proof that  $ay_1(t)+by_2(t)=0$ only if $a=0$ and $b=0$. And note that the $0$ in the first eqality is the **zero function**, i.e. the function that is null for all values of $x$ .

So it is not enough to show that $y_1$ and $y_2$ have different values for $t=0$. But, knowing that 
$$
ay_1(0)+by_2(0)= a v_1+bv_2=0 \iff a=\frac{-bv_2}{v_1}
$$

we can see that for the same values of $a$ and $b$ it is not possible that $$ay_1(x)+by_2(x)=0$$ is true also for other values of $t$ ( you can chose as $t=1$).

So  we see that we cannot have two not null values $a$ and $b$ such that $ay_1+by_2$ is the null function.

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not enough to show that $y_1$ and $y_2$ have different values for $t=0$" ?

Comment: From the fact that two functions are such that $y_1(0)=v_1$ and $y_2(0)=v_2$ with $v_1 \ne v_2$ we cannot conclude that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent.